# Extract the email address, and replacing a character using Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to come up with Reg ex expression that would match an email address starting with format E- and replacing the "AT" with an actual "@" sign.

Here is an example:

**E-CANAD.JACK AT EXAMPLE.COM**.

The desired output will need to look like **CANAD.JACK@EXAMPLE.COM**.

Comment: You don't even need regex to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
[eE]-([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*) (?:at|AT) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

By:

```
$1@$2
```

More:

- Visualization by
  [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/wPNOA-oYMzxxKDUq)
- Demo by [RegExr](http://regexr.com?36che)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your language, so I'm assuming `perl`

```
s/^E-(.*) AT (.*)$/$1\@$2/;
```

Comment: I am working with this expression which grabs the email **Match=(?<=//E-).*?(?=;)** after the E- However, i am trying to add "AT" replacement to it.